# What is наждалась?

Tags: перевод

From a song "Уходи, дверь закрой" by Евгения Отрадная

Уходи и дверь закрой,
У меня теперь другой,
Мне не нужен больше твой
номер в книжке записной,
Натерпелась, наждалась, <--------- *What's this?*
Я любовью обожглась,
Но теперь я наконец-то
Будто снова родилась!

Can someone please tell me what наждалась means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*на*+verb+*ся* is a circumfix (I don't know how technically correct it is to call it that but the two elements work as a whole) that means "to have had enough of [doing something]". It's probably an extrapolation from *наесться* and *напиться*, and it's productive, meaning that new words formed this way will sound natural.

So *наждалась* means "[I'm] done waiting."

Comment: Very interesting, similar to another prefix I've seen, ПОНА- as in ПОНАзакачивать "to download lots of (something)."

Comment: @CocoPop It can also be conveyed with just *на-* (most of the time; the classic *понаехали* can't). *пона-* makes it more expressive.

Comment: Are both на- and пона- in this sense always perfective?

Comment: @CocoPop Yes, unless reverse-imperfected with *-ыва-/-ива-*. (Except for directionless verbs of motion: *понаезжать, поналетать*, etc. are imperfective, but they wouldn't be used often.) (Wait... now I'm not sure. Which aspect is *понахватывать*? Apparently perfective. We need another opinion, I'm confused.)

Comment: Good explanation, just note that НАхххСЯ can have other meaning as well, e.g.  _нарваться_ (stumble upon), навязаться (inflict oneself upon) etc